# OpenWeatherMap API One call API.. It Just will not work? Am I dumb or is this something on their side?

Tags: javascript, api, openweathermap

So I subscribed to their API to get an Api Key and that took about an hour to become active. Working on my weather app project I came accross their One call Api which gives you a lot more data in one call. After I subscribe to this and pay, they send me an email with some example links. This is the complete example link they sent me(my API Key was attached but I deleted it to post here)...

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=33.44&lon=-94.04&appid=mykey

I copy the link to the browser and it says my key is invalid. I got other lat and lon coordinates and inserted them as well to see.(also removed my real key to post here)

https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=25.7741728&lon=-80.19362&exclude=hourly,daily&appid=mykey

Still nothing. I know the key is right because its already attached in the email they send me and just in case I also copied it from my account and still nothing. Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score -1):

It got activated for me after a day on subscribing the 3.0 api.. so please wait until it gets activated.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).